# is it possible that some write will happen between two migrations while rails db:migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is it possible that some write will happen between two migrations?

For example 2 files in folder db/migrate:
miration_file_1.rb
miration_file_2.rb

Im starting deploy to production, and `rails db:migrate` under the hood.

In chronological order:

1. deploy process executes miration_file_1.rb
2. meanwhile application executes "some query" to the DB
3. deploy process executes miration_file_2.rb

So the question is: "some query"(2) will be executed before (3) or after it?

`rails db:migrate` will put lock on DB until ALL migrations are completed?

Or it will put lock while first migration executed, then unlock and locks again for the second migration?

I cant find answer in documentation. It would be very helpfull to have a link to page where answers can be found.

Comment: ActiveRecord wraps individual migrations in transactions, but not the whole process. In any case, it does not lock the DB. Depending on [transaction isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html), your reads may or may not see changes from your migrations before they are complete.

Comment: If you need atomicity of the overall migration process from the app's point of view, then shut it down before migration and start it back after.

Comment: "Maintenance Mode" is your friend if you have these types of concerns. the `turnout` gem may work although it appears to be a bit stale. Also many PaaS providers offer simple maintenance mode mechanisms, for instance [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode)